# detect mouse events in mac os X at system level

Tags: macos

I would like to keep track of all mouse events at system level (not only in my application).
I've quickly googled this but found no real interesting pointer.

Do you know how to achieve this?

Thanks in adavance for your help :)

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of 2 ways: installing Carbon Event handlers on the event monitor target (`GetEventMonitorTarget`) or using a Quartz event tap (`CGEventTapCreate`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
Which method is the best in term of performance and/or compatibility?

Thanks

Comment: @AP: If you have previous experience with Carbon Events, that approach might be easier, but otherwise I'd say go with event taps, a newer API.